# Powershell - Updating XML Text under Count Node

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file that looks like this

```
<Transactions>
    <Transaction Type="Login">
        <LoginSetting>blahblah</LoginSetting>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction Type="Search">
        <Parameters>blahblah</Parameters>
        <Count>Setting</Count>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction Type="Logout">
        <LogoutSetting>blahblah</LogoutSetting>
    </Transaction>
</Transactions>
```

The path to this file is stored under $xml_path and using powershell I've imported those settings into [xml]$xml

```
[xml]$xml = (get-content $xml_path)
```

I'm trying to update the value under the "Count" node

```
$xml.Transactions.Transaction.Count = 'NewSetting'
```

Since .Count is something that can be run to get the number of nodes named "Transaction", powershell gives me this error output

```
'Count' is a ReadOnly property.
```

Is there another way to update the value under the "Count" node?

Comment: Yeah, this is a "by-design" kind of bug, you're getting the value of the synthetic "Count" property (ie. how many items are in `$xml.Transactions.Transaction`). Use `Select-Xml` or `SelectSingleNode()` to obtain a reference to the actual `<Count>` node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my workaround:
I imported the xml data into two variables - One as Flat Text and the other as XML

```
$xml_flat = (get-content $xml_path)
[xml]$xml = (get-content $xml_path)
```

I pulled the value for "Count" from the xml variable (since it won't necessarily have a value of 'Setting' as displayed)

```
$count = Select-Xml -XML $xml -XPath "//Count"
```

I ran a .replace against the flat variable to update the setting I needed to.

```
$xml_flat = $xml_flat.replace("<Count>$count</Count>","<Count>NewSetting</Count>")
```

From there i was able to import $xml_flat into an xml variable as $xml_new and am able to do whatever else I need to

```
[xml]$xml_new = $xml_flat
```